# not able to stream .m3u8 file on an android platform

Tags: android, http-live-streaming

i m trying to implement the http live streaming on an android platform. but for this(http://rajsimsan.site90.net/stream.m3u8) link of .m3u8 file my emulator is not playing the video. here is the main java code.

```
    /*
    * Copyright (C) 2009 The Android Open Source Project
    *
     * Licensed under the Apache License, Version 2.0 (the "License");
* you may not use this file except in compliance with the License.
* You may obtain a copy of the License at
*
*      http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0
*
* Unless required by applicable law or agreed to in writing, software
* distributed under the License is distributed on an "AS IS" BASIS,
* WITHOUT WARRANTIES OR CONDITIONS OF ANY KIND, either express or implied.
* See the License for the specific language governing permissions and
* limitations under the License.
  */

package com.example.testhls;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.media.AudioManager;
import android.media.MediaPlayer;
import android.media.MediaPlayer.OnBufferingUpdateListener;
import android.media.MediaPlayer.OnCompletionListener;
import android.media.MediaPlayer.OnPreparedListener;
import android.media.MediaPlayer.OnVideoSizeChangedListener;
  import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.SurfaceHolder;
import android.view.SurfaceView;


public class MediaPlayerDemo_Video extends Activity implements
    OnBufferingUpdateListener, OnCompletionListener,
    OnPreparedListener, OnVideoSizeChangedListener, SurfaceHolder.Callback {

private static final String TAG = "MediaPlayerDemo";
private int mVideoWidth;
private int mVideoHeight;
private MediaPlayer mMediaPlayer;
private SurfaceView mPreview;
private SurfaceHolder holder;
private String path;
private Bundle extras;
private static final String MEDIA = "media";
private boolean mIsVideoSizeKnown = false;
private boolean mIsVideoReadyToBePlayed = false;

/**
 * 
 * Called when the activity is first created.
 */
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle icicle) {
    super.onCreate(icicle);
    setContentView(R.layout.mediaplayer_2);
    mPreview = (SurfaceView) findViewById(R.id.surface);
    holder = mPreview.getHolder();
    holder.addCallback(this);
    holder.setType(SurfaceHolder.SURFACE_TYPE_PUSH_BUFFERS);
    extras = getIntent().getExtras();

}

private void playVideo(Integer Media) {
    doCleanUp();
    try {
        switch (Media) {
            case Globals.TEST_HTTP:
                path = "http://devimages.apple.com/iphone/samples/bipbop/gear1/prog_index.m3u8";
                break;
            case Globals.TEST_HTTPLIVE:
                path="http://rajsimsan.site90.net/stream.m3u8";
                //path = "smoothApple.isml/manifest(format=m3u8-aapl).m3u8";
                //httplive://devimages.apple.com/iphone/samples/bipbop/gear1/prog_index.m3u8
                break;
        }
        mMediaPlayer = new MediaPlayer();
        mMediaPlayer.setDataSource(path);
        mMediaPlayer.setDisplay(holder);
        mMediaPlayer.prepare();
        mMediaPlayer.setOnBufferingUpdateListener(this);
        mMediaPlayer.setOnCompletionListener(this);
        mMediaPlayer.setOnPreparedListener(this);
        mMediaPlayer.setOnVideoSizeChangedListener(this);
        mMediaPlayer.setAudioStreamType(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        Log.e(TAG, "error: " + e.getMessage(), e);
    }
}

public void onBufferingUpdate(MediaPlayer arg0, int percent) {
    Log.d(TAG, "onBufferingUpdate percent:" + percent);

}

public void onCompletion(MediaPlayer arg0) {
    Log.d(TAG, "onCompletion called");
}

public void onVideoSizeChanged(MediaPlayer mp, int width, int height) {
    Log.v(TAG, "onVideoSizeChanged called");
    if (width == 0 || height == 0) {
        Log.e(TAG, "invalid video width(" + width + ") or height(" + height + ")");
        return;
    }
    mIsVideoSizeKnown = true;
    mVideoWidth = width;
    mVideoHeight = height;
    if (mIsVideoReadyToBePlayed && mIsVideoSizeKnown) {
        startVideoPlayback();
    }
}

public void onPrepared(MediaPlayer mediaplayer) {
    Log.d(TAG, "onPrepared called");
    mIsVideoReadyToBePlayed = true;
    if (mIsVideoReadyToBePlayed && mIsVideoSizeKnown) {
        startVideoPlayback();
    }
}

public void surfaceChanged(SurfaceHolder surfaceholder, int i, int j, int k) {
    Log.d(TAG, "surfaceChanged called");

}

public void surfaceDestroyed(SurfaceHolder surfaceholder) {
    Log.d(TAG, "surfaceDestroyed called");
}


public void surfaceCreated(SurfaceHolder holder) {
    Log.d(TAG, "surfaceCreated called");
    playVideo(extras.getInt(MEDIA));


}

@Override
protected void onPause() {
    super.onPause();
    releaseMediaPlayer();
    doCleanUp();
}

@Override
protected void onDestroy() {
    super.onDestroy();
    releaseMediaPlayer();
    doCleanUp();
}

private void releaseMediaPlayer() {
    if (mMediaPlayer != null) {
        mMediaPlayer.release();
        mMediaPlayer = null;
    }
}

private void doCleanUp() {
    mVideoWidth = 0;
    mVideoHeight = 0;
    mIsVideoReadyToBePlayed = false;
    mIsVideoSizeKnown = false;
}

private void startVideoPlayback() {
    Log.v(TAG, "startVideoPlayback");
    holder.setFixedSize(mVideoWidth, mVideoHeight);
    mMediaPlayer.start();
}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at [Vitamio](https://www.vitamio.org/). They have a library that you can use — even on Android 2.1 devices — that allows you to play m3u8 feeds (amongst others).

Unfortunately, the emulator doesn't support the vitamio library, so you will have to do your testing on a physical device (or subscribe to a third-party real device testing service).

Comment: shabbirh one more thing....i m trying to play www.markmyfest.com/raj/stream.m3u8 in emulator(3.0) nothing happens.... but when i play the same link in apple tabs browser, it plays smoothly..... can u please tell wat might be the problem?

Comment: The emulators don't generally support things that require hardware acceleration. If you're developing professionally - the best thing to do is have a dev device and use that as your testing ground - don't rely on the emulator - that goes for all mobile platforms - Android, iOS, WP7, BB, etc -- Emulators are nice for sorting out your basic UI and such things - for testing real functionality and performance - nothing quite like a real device.

Hope that helps.

Comment: @shabbirh How to embed Vitamio SDK into our Andriod App?

Comment: @String  you can download [VitamioBundle](https://github.com/yixia/VitamioBundle) from github, it's include sample, it's so easy.

Comment: @Crossle Song Thanks,It got Worked?

Answer (score 0):

Can't we stream without m3u8 without vitamio?